# How to replace _NUM with _* using regsub

Tags: tcl

I want to convert both strings into `SML_CHAINS_6_*`  using regsub in tcl. How do I do that?
`SML_CHAINS_6_1167`
`SML_CHAINS_6_1145`

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
set var1 SML_CHAINS_6_1167
regsub {\d+$} $var1 "*" var1
```

and same for the other. Just replacing all trailing digits with a single asterisk.

Comment: I'd probably go with `_\d+$` -> `_*` for a little more safety, but that's about the same as what you wrote otherwise.